# Trigger on TTL deletion Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, database-trigger, ttl

I'm currently building an application in Java that uses a Cassandra database, and I would like to have a table that takes in data as it expires in another Cassandra table. Is there a way to implement a Trigger that can do this?

Answer (score 5):

The data doesnt actually expire on a timer or anything. The data is written to disk with the ttl. When read if the `ttl + writetime < now` it will consider it a tombstone instead of the data. Then after `gc_grace_seconds` it will end up being purged on a compaction. So while the data is expired, it maybe days depending on compaction strategy before its actually deleted from disk.

To answer question though, no you cannot.

Comment: Should not the line read as "When read if the ttl + writetime __**<**__ now; it will consider it a tombstone instead of the data. "